# TableLayout column sizing

Tags: android

I have a TableLayout with three columns that represents a form with

requiredSymbol | label | inputfield.

I want the input field to fill the remaining width of the screen right to the label. So far the only solution I found is this

```
<TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:stretchColumns="2">
    <TableRow>
                    <TextView android:text="@string/requiredSymbol"
                              />
     <TextView android:text="@string/Name"
                              android:textColor="@color/orange"
                              android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
         />
     <EditText android:id="@+id/contactName"
         android:inputType="text|textPersonName"
                              android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                            android:maxWidth="1sp"
                            />
    </TableRow>
```

The maxWidth needs to be there are some value, which is actually ignored. Then the stretchColumns value does its thing nicely. Note that this also works if the content of the EditText would otherwise make the table span beyond the screen border (imho a bug..).

This works nicely now but seems a little bit of a hack to me. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no better way at this stage that uses the static xml files. However I have since changed the layout to not have a separate column for the required label/icon and changed it to use the EditText#setError message combined with a TextWatcher implementation on each field, which is much nicer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try using android:layout_weight on the columns, but make sure you set android:stretchColumns in the TableLayout.  I've had problems with TableLayout unilaterally deciding to shrink columns causing unwanted text wrapping.  I'm not sure if the use of layout_weight and unilateral column shrinking are related.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I achieved this was by getting the `width` of the `EditText` field after it's added to the layout with width `FILL_PARENT`, and then using that to set the `MaxWidth`.

It comes out looking like this:

```
EditText exampleText = new EditText(this);
exampleText.setText([Your Text]);

//This says to fill width, but wrap content for the height
//So it should expand to whatever you've set the MaxLines to be...
LayoutParams exampleLP = new LayoutParams(FILL_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
[Parent].addView(exampleText, exampleLP);

//Here is where it's actually setting the width.
exampleText.setMaxWidth(exampleText.getWidth());
```

Not my favorite way, but it's definitely reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the EditText to match the remaining width by wrapping the EditText in a FrameLayout and setting the EditText to match_parent.  This seems to work for Spinners too.

```
<TableLayout
    android:shrinkColumns="1"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow>

        <!-- column 0 -->
        <TextView
            android:text="some text" />

        <!-- column 1 -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: This does not take the required symbol that might or might not be there into account..